# Unable to install MongoDB on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, mongodb

I cannot install MongoDB on my Linux Mint.

Operating System: Linux Mint 19.1

Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-50-generic

Architecture: x86-64

I followed [official documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Import the public key used by the package management system

```
$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Create a list file for MongoDB Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

```
$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" |
                    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Reload local package

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install the MongoDB package

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

While installing got these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  icoutils libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libtcmalloc-minimal4 libwine-development libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5
  libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongodb-server-core python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion
  wine64-development
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 245 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.3 MB/73.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 267 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-shell amd64 4.0.12 [9,865 kB]
Get:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-tools amd64 4.0.12 [38.5 MB]
Get:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org amd64 4.0.12 [3,528 B]
Fetched 48.3 MB in 31s (1,553 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 349983 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.0.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.0.12) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.12_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.0.12) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.12_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.0.12) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.0.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.0.12) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.12_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.12_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried to start the DB

```
$ sudo service mongod start

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

The command below gives the same error:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Unable to remove mongodb-server-core:

```
$ apt remove mongodb-server-core

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What is the source of the `mongodb-server-core` listed in the "no longer required" section of the output?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems like you have an older version already installed: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.12_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1` You could try `apt remove mongodb-server-core` (To remove the old version). You should be able to test the old version by running `/usr/bin/mongod`. You may not have a service file for that, that may be why it isn't starting now (the old version).

Comment: @rudib I tried to remove mongodb-server-core but it says that "You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies,....  Same as previous error

Comment: I see. Could you update your post with the full info?

Comment: @rudib info updated

Comment: Maybe try to remove `mongodb-org` first. `apt remove mongodb-org`.

Comment: @rudib it worked,Thanks. Can please add it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is conflict with mongodb-server-core
Try to

```
sudo apt-get purge mongod*
sudo apt-get update
```

and re-install

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  Nothing I found online worked.  But eventually guessed a solution that did.

Instead of

```
sudo apt-get purge mongod*
```

I did

```
sudo apt-get purge mongo*
```

then problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was me on Ubuntu machine.

```bash
sudo apt-get purge mongod*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The above commands help.